# How can i wait for a process tree so finished?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I have some updating to do when my application comes from the background, but some updates are dependent on a certain function that although executes first, it finishes after the other update methods(it calls a bunch of chained functions).

How can i ensure that a function tree is finished so that i may then execute the rest of the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked at `NSOperationQueue`? It enables you to specify dependencies among `NSOperation`s so that you can rely on certain execution orders to be followed.

Answer (score 0):

This might work, with wait untill done flag set to YES. Give it a shot.

- (void)performSelector:(SEL)aSelector 
  onThread:(NSThread *)thr withObject:(id)arg waitUntilDone:(BOOL)wait;

Apple doc says that setting the waitUntillDone on YES will stop the current thread untill your selector has finished its execution.

> wait - A Boolean that specifies whether the current thread blocks until
>   after the specified selector is performed on the receiver on the
>   specified thread. Specify YES to block this thread; otherwise, specify
>   NO to have this method return immediately. If the current thread and
>   target thread are the same, and you specify YES for this parameter,
>   the selector is performed immediately on the current thread. If you
>   specify NO, this method queues the message on the thread’s run loop
>   and returns, just like it does for other threads. The current thread
>   must then dequeue and process the message when it has an opportunity
>   to do so.

Let me know if it worked.